# How to perform Teams Channel Authentication for bot framework?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am working on team's bot that is scoped to teams' channel and group chat. I am using a external service that is being used by the bot. Now if I add the bot to channel or group chat, i want a way to only authorize certain group of users or use their auth token to access the external service within bot. In a personal chat as given by the example 46. (link: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/46.teams-auth) Teams auth in Bot framework samples, we can do auth when we click sign in and the user gets to login then pass the token to the bot. How to perform the same action (bit less intrusive) in a channel or a group chat?

Comment: Did you try adding channel in Bot's scope in the manifest?

Comment: Could you please share the above asked details?

Comment: It works fine if you add team scope in the Bot's scope.